# Eclipse Compare Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, compare

I wrote a plugin for Eclipse that need to compare two existing .java files.
I want to open a "Compare with Other Resources" dialog from code, but i cant find any tutorials for that.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This may help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F

Answer (score 0):

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String [] {"*.html"});
dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\temp");
String result = dialog.open();
```

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_prompt_the_user_to_select_a_file_or_a_directory%3F

But how is your plugin structured? Extends a view? Are you using the jdt classes to select resources from a project?

**EDIT**

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcompare%2FCompareUI.html

This class is probably a good starting point. A search on bugzilla in eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=108951

states this class as internal. It may not be wise to use it

Comment: http://www.eclipseonetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Compare_With_Other_Resource_Dialog.png

I need this dialog.